# How to bind v4l2 USB cameras to the same device names even after reboot?

Tags: linux, video

I have 3 USB cameras on single PC, one camera will be unused and can be ignored.
I need to force two identical cameras to be mapped to constant device names (like `/dev/video1` and `/dev/video2` ). The cameras should not change their order (say camera 1 mounted as `video1` and camera 2 as `video2` after disconnect they should be in same order not camera1 --> `/dev/video2`, camera2 --> `/dev/video1`. How to make this setup work?

I will feed camera output to *Gstreamer*. Cameras are using *v4l2* and *uvc* driver interface. Linux distro in question is *Archlinux*, cameras - some Logitech webcams.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest you autocreate `/dev` symlinks using `udev`, using unique properties (serial number? port number?) of your USB cameras.  See this (should apply to Arch as well) [tutorial about udev rules](https://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-admin_sd_draft/cha.udev.html#sec.udev.rules).  Or [maybe this tutorial is clearer](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-printer).

You can get the list of properties for your devices using:

```
sudo udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/video1
```

then

```
sudo udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/video2
```

Find what's different and create a `.rules` file out of it inside `/etc/udev/rules.d` (you can use `99-myvideocards.rules` as a filename, say); let's say you want to use the serial number, you'd get a ruleset that looks like:

```
ATTRS{ID_SERIAL}=="0123456789", SYMLINK+="myfirstvideocard"
ATTRS{ID_SERIAL}=="1234567890", SYMLINK+="mysecondvideocard"
```

After unplugging/replugging your devices (or after a reboot), you'll get `/dev/myfirstvideocard` and `/dev/mysecondvideocard` that always point to the same devices.

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it works, I will "close" question with your answer ;D But in meantime I found that v4l already have symlinks like `/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_0819_92E84F10-video-index0`

Comment: How do you change the 'friendly name' found in the settings of programs like Teamspeak or Discord? I tried `, ID_V4L_PRODUCT="C920 (1)"` but it's probably not even correct rules.d syntax.

Answer (score 7):

Patrice Levesque method works fine, but I found that there are already symlinks in Linux as `/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_0819_92E84F10-video-index0` in folder `/dev/v4l/by-id/` so no need to do anything, if ones program can accept arguments other than `/dev/videoX`.

Comment: While the other answer is correct, I think this is the more practical answer.  I've confirmed this with Raspbian and Ubuntu (so at least Debian-based OS's it seems).  Not sure if this a standard v4l feature across all distros or not.